# PHP out of memory at 200MB in CLI but fine in browser

Tags: php, out-of-memory, command-line-interface, cpanel

I am running out of memory when using command line when logged in over SSH as a user `mike`.

When I run the script via browser or via command line as `root`, its all good and stalls at 1000M as expected.

The test script I am using is:

```
<pre>
<?php 
echo //phpinfo();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

for ($i=1; $i<1500; $i+=50) {
  $a = loadmem($i);
  echo "You have allocated ". $i . "M (". memory_get_usage() . ") memory in this php script" . "<br />";
  unset($a);
}

function loadmem($howmuchmeg) {
  $a = str_repeat("0", $howmuchmeg * 1024 * 1024); // alocating 10 chars times million chars  
  return $a;
}
?>
</pre>
```

When I run as user `mike` the script errors at around 200M.

I am using php-fpm and tried both PHP 5.6 and 7.2 and tried both `memory_limit` settings as 1000M.

When I run this as `mike`:

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

I get:

```
memory_limit => 1000M => 1000M
```

I cannot for the life of me see where it's getting this 200M limit from.

Is there any reason why a user account would restrict memory usage over root?

Comment: There should be a config file for cli in /etc/php/[version]/cli/ , did you also change that one?

Comment: Hi yep, changed that one.

Comment: I have a feeling its something to do with cPanels 'Shell Fork Bomb Protection' as there is a setting of '-m 200000' in '/etc/profile.d/limits.sh'. However upon disabling this or increasing the limit, im still having the same problem. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The *ini* files used for your server(browser) and the cli are different.
You can either specify a configuration file using `-c` or get the location of php's cli configuration file by
`$ php -i |grep php\.ini`

Comment: hi, I should have mentioned, I tried to load a specific config file, same problem. And I ran that command and edited that config file to 1000M, same problem.

Comment: Can you please restart the PHP service or reboot the remote/local system to ensure that the new configuration file is loaded?

Comment: rebooted the server and it solved the issue! thanks. rebooting php service didnt seem to work!

Comment: @MikeMeade In most cases its always one of the two. You can upvote and accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

It can be file permission issue on the php.ini file.

> If you find that memory limits differ between root and other users
>   when PHP scripts are run from the command line, there may be an issue
>   with your php.ini or your script. To verify that it isn’t your script,
>   try this:
>
> ```
> $ echo "<? var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit')); ?>" >> memtest.php
> $ php -f memtest.php
> string(3) "8M"
> $ su -
> # php -f memtest.php
> string(3) "64M"
> ```
>
> If you get the same two values from both users, there’s probably a
>   problem with your script. Make sure that there’s no ini_set()
>   functions in your script that are overriding the php.ini file.
>
> However, if you get results like the ones above, check the permissions
>   on /etc/php.ini:
>
> ```
> # ls -al /etc/php.ini
> -rw-------  1 root root 27 Jun  6 18:39 /etc/php.ini
> ```
>
> As you can see, php.ini is only readable to root, which prevents PHP’s
>   command line parser from accessing your custom memory_limit directive
>   in the php.ini. PHP’s general default is 8M for a memory limit if
>   nothing is specified anywhere else, and that’s why normal users cannot
>   get the higher memory limit that’s set in your php.ini file.
>
> Simply set the permissions on the file to 644 and you should be set to
>   go:
>
> ```
> # chmod 644 /etc/php.ini
> # ls -al /etc/php.ini
> -rw-r--r--  1 root root 45022 Jun  6 23:00 /etc/php.ini
> ```

Source: https://major.io/2007/06/14/php-cli-memory-limit-is-different-between-users-and-root/

Because you run through with apache (I think) than maybe that user can't access the php.ini file. Also please note, for cli and for apache (script run) there's two different ini files. Also some distributions splited up the ini files, in those case the last variable set will be applied (if the same value was set in multiple files which are loaded).